# Automapper find best mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper with Entity Framework. I have a hierarchy of entities:

- Person

  - Student
  - Worker

Each business object has a map to an entity in the database. To convert the business objects into entities I'm using AutoMapper v6.2.2
I wonder if there is a better way to find the "best" mapping or do I really need to have something like this in code:

```
    public PersonEntity MapPerson(Person person)
    {
        switch (person.Type)
        {
            case PersonType.Unknown:
                return Mapper.Map<PersonEntity>(person);
            case PersonType.Student:
                return Mapper.Map<StudentEntity>(person);
            case PersonType.Worker:
                return Mapper.Map<WorkerEntity>(person);

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

The good thing is, I already have a "Type" enum for discriminator and things like that but it still feels wrong. Maybe you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this...

```
var mapped = Mapper.Map(person, person.GetType(), typeof(PersonEntity));
```

Please refer to the AutoMapper docs for more details.
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know that automapper has such good docs.

Answer (score 1):

AutoMapper is capable of [mapping inheritance](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html). The mapping should look like this:

```
class PersonMapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public PersonMapperProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Student, StudentEntity>();
        this.CreateMap<Worker, WorkerEntity>();
        this.CreateMap<Person, PersonEntity>()
            .Include<Student, StudentEntity>()
            .Include<Worker, WorkerEntity>();
    }
}
```

Now when you map a `Person` to `PersonEntity`, AutoMapper will create the correct base type or sub types.